# Number of Lines that can be drawn with DrawLines Method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, graph, system.drawing

I am drawing a series of lines on a PrintPreviewControl using the DrawLines method.  Here is my code where I take x and y values and convert them into coordinates inside a page rectangle, adding them to a list. I then call DrawLines with a pen and the list converted to an array. I have found that DrawLines will only draw 8125 lines using 8126 point pairs. I receive no exception when DrawLines fails. Any way to increase the number of point pairs that DrawLines will use? Alternatively, I could draw each line individually, or I could parse the points array into 8000 point blocks.

```
Private Sub DrawGammaLog(ByVal gr As Graphics)
  Try
    'draw log in chart area
    If Points.Count <> 0I Then
      gr.SetClip(LogRect)
      Dim LPoints As New List(Of PointF)
      For Each pt In Points
        Dim PointY As Single = LogRect.Top + ((pt.Depth - VScaleMinValue) * VScale)
        Dim PointX As Single = LogRect.Left + (pt.Count * HScale)
        If PointY >= LogRect.Top AndAlso PointY <= LogRect.Bottom Then
          LPoints.Add(New PointF(PointX, PointY))
        End If
      Next
      Debug.Print("{0}", LPoints.Count)
      If LPoints.Count >= 2I Then gr.DrawLines(gpp.LogPen, LPoints.ToArray)
    End If
    'draw box around chart area
    gr.DrawRectangle(gpp.LogPen, Rectangle.Round(LogRect))
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString & ", " & ex.Source.ToString, Me.Text & " DrawGammaLog")
  Finally
    gr.ResetClip()
  End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here using c# in Visual Studio 2010. 8125 seems to be the limit, even if there are no references to this problem online...

I have splitted my array into 8000 PointF[] array blocks as a work-around.

```
int counter = 0;
int block_size = Math.Min(data.Length, 8000);
PointF[] data_subset;

while (counter != data.Length)
{
    data_subset = new PointF[block_size];
    Array.Copy(data, counter, data_subset, 0, data_subset.Length);
    g.DrawLines(p, data_subset);

    counter += block_size;
    block_size = Math.Min(data.Length - counter, 8000);
}
```